# REST API alternative to "docker trust inspect"

Tags: api, docker, trust

Context: trying to find the way to retrieve the keys from signed docker image using golang or curl

Question: Is there docker REST API endpoint that would allow me to get the keys, similar  to command `docker trust inspect`